# laravel vuejs form submit returns to the same page with query string

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i am trying to submit a form with laravel and vuejs in a component like below :

```
          <form action="#" @submit.prevent="submitMobile">
            <div class="container my-5 z-depth-1">
                    <!-- Form -->
                    <form class="" action="">
                      <!-- Section heading -->
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control send-sms-btn" name="mobile"
                               v-validate="'required:11'" placeholder="_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"
                               aria-label="Enter your email address"
                               aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn-theme btn btn-md btn-primary rounded-right m-0 px-3 py-2 z-depth-0 waves-effect"
                                  type="submit" id="button-addon2">submit
                          </button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </form>
          </form>
```

and here is my vuejs :

```
    export default {
        props: [

        ],

        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        },

        methods: {   
          sendContactFormServer() {

            axios({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/customer/send-sms',
              data: {
                "mobile": this.form.mobile,
              },
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'appllication/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
              }
            })
                .then(window.location.href = "/")
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
          },
          submitMobile: function() {
            this.$http.post('/customer/send-sms', this.formData).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            }, function() {
              console.log('failed');
            });
          }
        }
    }
```

i tried 2 functions but both of them returns me to the same page with the query string of the input i have send . now i want to know how can i submit this form without refreshing the page . thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try `this.$router.push()`

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

```js
submitMobile: function() {
    this.$http.post('/customer/send-sms', this.formData).then(function(response) {
    
    this.$router.push({
        name: "route_name", // tis route name you need to add 
        query: { mobile: this.mobile },  
    });

    }, function() {
    console.log('failed');
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks its fine but it cant real the mobile field thats so wierd

Comment: you need query in url right ? like `localhost?mobile=9809`

Comment: no every thing is fine now but my form is not submitting any field and i get 500 error . am i doing any thing wrong in submitting my data ?

Comment: show me what 500 error ? your getting check i network tab

Comment: i saw that it says the mobile field is missing in my controller and when i console log the mobile it just prints nothing and when i alert it its an empty alert

Comment: then check your `this.formData`

Comment: undefined when i alert it